# Recycling Item objects in XPages Domino Java

Tags: java, xpages

I have some code:

```
Document doc = view.getFirstDocument();
Item item = null;

if (null != admin.getManagers())
{
    doc.replaceItemValue("Managers", admin.getManagers());
    item = doc.getFirstItem("Managers");
    item.setNames(true);
} 
else
{
    doc.replaceItemValue("Managers", "");
}

// Load the workers and set them as Names fields
if (null != admin.getWorkers())
{
    doc.replaceItemValue("Workers", admin.getWorkers());
    item = doc.getFirstItem("Workers");
    item.setNames(true);
} 
else
{
    doc.replaceItemValue("Workers", "");
}
```

in the finally section, I recycle the document

```
finally 
{
    if(null != doc)
    {
        doc.recycle();
    }
}
```

My question is: should I recycle the `Item` in the same way? or does it get recycled as it is a child of the `Document`? or should I be using separate variables for each item and recycling them individually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you recycling the document then all document's item objects are recycled automatically too. You don't need to recycle those explicitly.

You would have to recycle items manually if you'd iterate through a lot of items within current document, let's say many thousands. As that is probably not the case you don't have to.

You have at least 18,000 handles for Domino objects per request (in version 8.5 - even more in version 9.0). If you can get close to that number then recycle. If not don't worry.

**Update**

I did some experimental research regarding handles and recycling. Here are my results:

- there is no number of used Domino objects (handles) without recycling before server crashed *as limit* but an internal object cache in memory
- Domino objects occupy a different amount of caches's memory depending on type

  - about 500,000 Items can be handled in cache before server crashes
  - about 300,000 Items with a name longer than 23 character
  - about 400,000 Items of type DateTime
  - about 9,500,000 DateTime objects created with session.createDateTime(Date)
  - about 258,100,000 DateTime objects created with session.createDateTime(String)
- Domino 8.5.3 and 9.0.1 servers show exactly the same results
- http requests running at the same time have to **share** handle memory
- http requests recycle all used objects at request's end
- DateTime objects don't use objects cache if they are created with session.createDateTime(Calendar)
- DateTime objects get recycled completely when parent document gets recycled if they got instantiated from item `DateTime dateTime = item.getDateTimeValue()`

I used Java code called by an XPage for my experiments.

This is one variation of it:

Java

```java
package de.leonso.test;
import lotus.domino.Database;
import lotus.domino.Document;
import lotus.domino.NotesException;
import com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoUtils;

public class Crasher {
    public static void crash() throws NotesException {
        Database database = DominoUtils.getCurrentDatabase();
        for (long docNumber = 1; docNumber <= 100000; docNumber++) {
            Document doc = database.createDocument();
            doc.replaceItemValue("Number", Long.valueOf(docNumber));
            for (int itemNumber = 3; itemNumber <= 1000; itemNumber++) {
                doc.replaceItemValue("Item" + itemNumber, itemNumber);
            }
            System.out.println(docNumber);
            doc.save();
        }
    }
}
```

XPage

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:text
        escape="true"
        id="computedField1">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
            de.leonso.test.Crasher.crash(); 
            "finished"
        }]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:text>
</xp:view>
```

This code creates 492 documents before server crashes. At this time at least 492,000 Domino object handles are in use.

Comment: one addition to Knut's answer, if you get any NotesDateTime objects from the doc, then these are not recycled with the doc, as they are children of the NotesSession not the Doc. same concept if iterating NotesViewEntries. so NotesDateTime's need to be recycled deliberately. otherwise they will start filling up your quota of handles (but they will be recycled at the end of the request along with the session)

Comment: Please, can you back up that 18k handles per request statement? I am aware of 10k internal limit of C API for whole server, not request. Therefore heavy usage of HTTP (let's say 100 active threads) may down the server with only 100 handles in one loop without recycling.

Comment: @Cameron: I couldn't find evidence in my tests that DateTime values make special recycling trouble. I haven't tested ViewEntries yet.

Comment: @Frantisek: your comment motivated myself to do some tests. So, there is no 18K or 10K limit. The limit is near 500K. You are right about simultaneous active HTTP requests: they have to share object handle memory. So, the actual handle limit might be way lower per thread.

Comment: Hi Knut, I'm not sure how your have performed your experiments re DateTime but your statement that they don't use any handle memory doesn't match with my own experience or the following article. (see Section IV a and b)
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Java_memory_management_in_NotesDomino
are you using setPreferJavaDates(true) ?

Comment: also https://nathantfreeman.wordpress.com/2013/07/03/a-funny-thing-happened-on-the-way-to-the-openntf-webinar/

Comment: @Cameron: still testing. session.createDateTime(String) and session.createDateTime(calendar) don't  use handle memory whereas session.createDateTime(Date) crashes server after 9,500,000 calls. Weird.

Comment: thanks Knut keep us updated. From my experience our server was crashing when loading X amount of records (from document into POJOs) and we were recycling doc on each iteration. When I made one change so that it would deliberately recycle any datetimes as well, then it no longer crashed. tested also with twice as many records as previous.
For your test are you using the same date over and over? or are you modifying to make sure there is no caching that the API might do that you don't know about? also what is the crash message you get "java OutOfMemory" or "LSXBE out of backend memory"?

Comment: @Cameron: the crash message is always "LSXBE: ****** Out of Backend Memory *******. I set for every call a different dateTime value - I add every loop a second to start time. The result from night run is: session.createDateTime(Calendar) had 1,000,000,000 loops without crash and session.createDateTime(String) crashed after 258,100,000 calls.

Comment: @Knut any chance I can get the java code that you are using regarding the datetime crash/recycle testing? maybe as an xsnippet ?